# Hide Last Modified time on apaches directory index/listing

Tags: apache, unix, .htaccess

I have this set up in my .htaccess

```
Options +Indexes 
IndexOptions -FancyIndexing
```

but even with -fancyindexing, it shows the modification time. How do you disable this?

thanks

Comment: Here's a [place to start looking](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want (From Apache's docs on [IndexOptions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions)):

```
IndexOptions SuppressLastModified
```

Documentation states:

> This will suppress the display of the
>   last modification date, in fancy
>   indexing listings.

So you'll probably want fancy indexing turned on to have this work correctly.